# accessing a .svc URL in ASP.NET 4.0, IIS 7.5 returns 404

Tags: .net, wcf, sitecore

Having done quite a bit of research on this let me state the following:

- The target framework is .NET 4, 64-bit
- The necessary Handlers are registered with IIS, for both .NET 2 and .NET 4, 32/64 bit
- I am expecting the service to run over HTTP
- The service is part of a larger web application that runs both WebForms and MVC 3.0
- The Routing Table includes an Ignore entry for {resource}.svc
- The solution does not work locally or when deployed to other servers
- The web application is Sitecore 6.6, and I have an Ignore Prefixes set for the folder where the *.svc file is located.

For the extremely interested, I am attempting to set up the Sitecore Modules WeBlog comment service.

Any ideas?

Comment: 404 can be a configuration problem with the service itself, like no WebGet permissions. How are you trying to access the service - just in the browser, or with the WCF test client? If you post your basic service contract and web.config, that will help to diagnose. (The problem might still be sitecore, of course - but that's by no means certain).

Comment: Well, this morning's problem ended up being a bit prosaic after the long weekend. There was a bad setting in my hosts file that prevented IIS from responding with the right site. Fixing that revealed the service description page in the browser as expected. I'll leave this open for a few more hours while I troubleshoot, but it might be closeable.

Comment: Heh. I forgot to add that the problem might be, ahem, human error... :) Probably best to close and post another if you hit more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems involved, neither was directly related to WCF configuration.

1. A bad hosts file entry on my local PC was getting in the way.
2. IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite rules for canonical hostname, trailing slash, and lowercase URLs were corrupting the WCF communications stream.

Disabling the URL Rewrite rules fixed the problem.